# can I run a .php file in the background?

Tags: php, apache, process

I there,

On user registration i am importing a lot of info from 3rd party services,

but the problem is that page takes a lot to load, is there a way to run this 'import' process in the background? (so user doesn't have to wait so much to see the page and probably on next refresh the imports would be finished)

thanks

Comment: Have u considered getting those info by ajax calls thus rending the page instantly and showing a graceful loader while the info loads?

Comment: Just thinking aloud...You can run a PHP file on the server via cron, say every 5 minutes, which checks if a new user is registered. If so, it can initiate the import process and after the process finishes, marks "complete" in db column. You can read this and display the info correspondingly.

Comment: @LoneWOLFs yes but the problem is that if user closes the ajax, then the process is aborted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to break down the registration process into two steps: a lightweight page that loads without waiting for the import to complete and another script that does the heavy lifting. The first would trigger the second with AJAX. The end result would be a "your registration is being processed" page which updates appropriately when the worker script finishes.

You should be careful to call [`ignore_user_abort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) at the beginning of the worker script so that the registration process is not aborted if the user closes the browser window while on the waiting page.

Comment: ignore_user_abort will let the script run even if it was called asynchronously and the users cloes the MAIN tab?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet: As far as the server is concerned there are no asynchronous calls or main tabs. All of those are only applicable to the client's perspective.

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet: Yes, but you don't have to take my word for it: try it for yourself.

Comment: yes sure i will, i am evaluating solutions for now. if this one works, seems to be the easiest for me. thaks! will try and let you know